# How to create gradle dependency from pom.xml file in android?

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, pom.xml

I am using https://www.route4me.com Route4me api for route optimization with an android app.I need to add gradle dependency of route4me api but no gradle dependency is found in documemt https://github.com/route4me/route4me-java-sdk .Only a pom.xml file is there which has maven dependency .How to convert this route4me pom.xml to gradle dependencies ?
I have tried using   **implementation 'com.route4me:route4me-java-sdk:RELEASE-1.3.1'**  and adding this maven {
url "https://www.route4me.com"
}  into build.gradle project but an error occured. Failed to resolve: com.route4me:route4me-java-sdk:RELEASE-1.3.1

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at their support pages, analysis of the pom file on github and search of all main Maven repo's suggests that they have not published this package as a built library to anywhere.

Thus you cannot use it as a normal dependency, you have to compile the source code yourself.